# ConstraintLayout fails to properly size or locate ImageView

Tags: android-layout, imageview, android-constraintlayout

Sorry I had to remove the Image due to copyright issues

My XML below is trying to place the email icon left justified, as it is.  But the size ignores my 3% height specification.  I can change the XML in many ways, but no matter what it wants to make the image 60 pixels wide, which is the size it is appearing on the screen and the size of the actual png.  All of the scaleType choices just change the image within the 60x60 space on the screen.  I really need it to be 3% of the screen height, which in this case, on the emulator is 3% of 480 pixels.

The image with the large email icon is with the constraintDimension line in the XML.

The image with the tiny email image is with that line removed.  Note that it is not left justified and that it is partially cropped.

The below and left constraints are both guidelines.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editing_top"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.03"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_indent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_mail"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/icon_mail"
        />[![Unhappy screenshot][1]][1]
```

Comment: On the top image, is the icon height correct? You just need to have it left-justified and not cutoff on the right? Can you share you full XML file, or the part that demonstrates the problem within the context? If you can also share you PNG of the mail icon, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You state that the height of the image should be 3% of the height of the layout (`app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.03"`), but you also state that the dimension ration should be 1:1 (`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`). These are in conflict.

Remove `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` and the height of the `ImageView` will go to 3% of the screen height and the width will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Removing the constantDimension did not fix it.  I had added that earlier trying to find a solution.  If I can, I will add a photo of what it looks like after removing that line.

Comment: Which version of ConstraintLayout are you using?

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'

Comment: @BobLissner Try version 1.1.0. It's the latest production release.

Comment: That made no difference.  Thanks for staying with me on this.

Comment: I had all my icons in Drawable.  Moved them to Drawable-xxhdpi and the problem went away for xxhdpi devices but remains for smaller devices.

Comment: @BobLissner Very strange. Try moving the drawable to `-nodpi` folder and deleting it from the Drawable folder to see if it correct for lower-density devices.

Comment: I am beginning to believe that ConstraintLayout has a bug sizing Imageviews when the height is a percent.  Here it is very nicely in PercentRelativeLayout, and it works great there.    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/email_icon"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="30%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="3%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mail"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/icon_mail"
            />

Comment: @BobLissner Can you post the email icon?

Comment: It turns out that if I restrict the width of the icon, which is a 60x60 png, it works great.  I say this is a bug in ConstraintLayout that restricting the height of an ImageView gives bad results.  Perhaps you would report it, because with your extensive history with ConstraintLayout, they might just believe you.  Thank you Cheticamp.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the last note.  I believe that     app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.03" for ImageViews is buggy, maybe only if the icon width is greater than the number of pixels it should be reduced to, maybe just older devices.